# Replace apply logic with something else

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a small df (173, 21).

I wrote a function that works, however I am using apply() and I would like to, if possible,
do it another way only because of apply()'s reputation for being slow.

On this particular data set it doesn't matter at all as it is so small, but I am trying
to avoid apply() if possible.

The function takes in a row, checks each of five columns (see code below), and if the value
in any given cell is 'YES' increment a counter.  Possible cell values are 'YES', 'NO' or 'NaN'

Here is the working code:

```
def clean_deaths(row):
    num_deaths = 0
    columns = ['Death1', 'Death2', 'Death3', 'Death4', 'Death5']

    for c in columns:
        death = row[c]
        if death == 'YES':
            num_deaths += 1
    return num_deaths


true_avengers['Deaths'] = true_avengers.apply(clean_deaths, axis=1)
total = true_avengers['Deaths'].sum()
print(total, '\n')  # 88
```

Comment: Isn't that just `df.eq('YES').sum(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: you should avoid `apply(..., axis=1)`.

Try this:

```
true_avengers['Deaths'] = (true_avengers[['Death1', 'Death2', 'Death3', 'Death4', 'Death5']] =='YES').sum(axis=1)
```